# python/django difference between dates, and ratio for progress bar

Tags: python, django, datetime, progress-bar

I'm trying to make an automatic `progressBar`, that takes the `end_date` of an event and the `beggining_date` and gives you the ratio of completion of the event, like 20% complete or 40% complete, etc.

I think there might me multiple errors in my code, but currently I'm getting an `AttributeError` `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'time_progress'`
.The idea is to call the `time_progress()`, and it will return the completion ratio.

My code:

**models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    # other Fields above
    beginning_date = models.DateTimeField("Beggining date")
    end_date = models.DateField("Completion date")

    def time_progress(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        progress = ((now - self.beginning_date).days/((self.end_date - now).days + (now - self.beginning_date).days))*100
        return progress
```

**views.py**

```
class EventView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Event

    template_name = 'info/event.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EventView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['progress'] = Event.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')).time_progress()
        return context
```

**event.html**

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar"
                aria-valuenow="{{ progress }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{ progress }}%">{{ progress }}%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Event.objects.filter` returns a queryset instead of an instance. Since you're using `DetailView`, self.get_object() will be a better choice to get the object. Otherwise, you could resort to `get_object_or_404` or `Event.objects.get()` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DetailView` already includes an `{{ object }}` in it's context.  You do not need a custom `get_context_data` method, instead, use in your template:

```
... style="width:{{ object.time_progress }}%" ...
```

If you do want to create `progress` in the template, consider using `{% with progress=object.time_progress %}...{% endwith %}` or fix your `get_context_data`:

```
context['progress'] = self.object.time_progress()
```

You might also want to round down the value (probably with `int()`)

Comment: Thanks, it really helped. I also fixed the progress to `progress = ((now - self.beginning_date)/(self.end_date - self.beginning_date)) * 100` and added  `return int(progress)`